# How to return only users where all of the user's account numbers are in another list

Tags: sql

How can I do a join or some SQL to return the loginNames from table 1 which have all of their actNumber's listed in table 2?

table 1

```
loginName     actNumber
joe123        981651
joe123        916516
dan456        315654
dan456        316881
amy333        691654
```

table 2

```
actNumber
916516
315654
316881
691654
```

Comment: I don't know how to only return if ALL account numbers for a give loginName exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` of `table1` to `table2` and `group by loginname`.
Then in the `HAVING` clause keep only the `loginname`s for which there is no `null` `actnumber` in table2:

```
select loginname
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.actnumber = t1.actnumber
group by loginname 
having sum(case when t2.actnumber is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3dcf271b8138df867403ce834e827f4d).
Results:

```
> | loginname |
> | :-------- |
> | amy333    |
> | dan456    |
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an INNER JOIN of the two tables on the actNumber column. This will produce a result set containing only actNumber records that exist in both table 1 and table 2.

For example,

`SELECT TABLE_1.loginName
 FROM TABLE_1 AS tbl1 INNER JOIN TABLE_2 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.actNumber = tbl2.actNumber`

Comment: But I don't want joe123 to be returned because actNumber 981651 is not in table 2.  The INNER JOIN returns joe123 with actNumber 916516.